# Ajax is entering success without calling the url on page load. it is calling aft4er deleting cache

Tags: ajax, caching, extjs

In my page I am making an ajax request & in success I am building tabs of page.
And user can change the tabs & save the layout.

So after refreshing again this ajax has to make call & from database it needs to bring saved tabs list. on which the tabs need to be built.

But in my case, even i have written all my code in success, it is entering success & building tabs on old list only..
not with the new list.
even the response is coming as old list only..

& in fidler I am not able to see the url call.

But when i delete the cache at that time url call also goes & it is able to load with new tabs list.

Comment: can you post your code for your ajax request? also, can you provide a sample of the response from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response is still the old list your data isn't being saved in your backend, verify your database that the records are in fact saved.

If you are sending over POST client side caching shouldn't be the problem, if it is a GET request check firebug if the cachebuster parameter is being sent along. This is an extra GET parameter _dc that is being sent with each request to prevent GET responses from being cached by the browser.

Are you perhaps using some kind of reverse proxy by any chance like Varnish or Squid?

Comment: thanks for yuor guidance...  I was able to fix this issue by sending as a post instead of get as post is never catched.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if you found my answer helpful :) Glad you sorted it out anyway.